# View tiddler with source code in pre block with syntax highlighting

Tags: syntax-highlighting, tiddlywiki, tiddlywiki5

I have a tiddler that contains SQL source code. I am embedding it into another tiddler using the `$codeblock` macro, and that works wonderfully.

When I view the source tiddler (the first one), I'd like to get it formatted like the embedded one (in a `pre` block with syntax highlighting applied).

I noticed Tiddlywiki can do this for Stylesheets, when you set a tiddler type to `text/css`. How can I do the same for other custom types? I've combed the docs but haven't found anything so far, but I freely admit I may be using the wrong terminology in my search. I've also struggled to find the source code that does the `pre` wrapping for stylesheet tags.

Anyone know how I'd do this?